# How to restart remote Websphere Application Server 7?

Tags: websphere, wsadmin

How to restart remote **Websphere Application Server 7**?
e.g. with helps of `wsadmin`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use wsadmin to connect to the deployment manager or the node agent.

Get a reference to the server that you are after and then start it

$AdminControl startServer serverName

This is how you start a server in wsadmin.

The server name should be replaced by the reference that you get from the dmgr or the nodeagent when you query it for your server

e.g. nodeServers = AdminConfig.getid('/Node:mynode/Server:/')
would list the server on node - my node.

HTH

Manglu